# Dynamically calculating oozie parameter (number of reducers for MR action)

Tags: hadoop, oozie

In my oozie workflow I dynamically create a hive table, say T1. This hive action is then followed by a map-reduce action. I want to set number of reducers property (mapred.reduce.tasks) equal to distinct values of a field say (T1.group). Any ideas how to set value of some oozie parameter dynamically and how to get value of the parameter from hive distinct action to oozie parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope this can help:

1. Create the hive table as you are doing already.
2. Execute another Hive query which calculates the distinct values for the column and writes it to a file in hdfs.
3. Create an `Shell` action, which will read the file and echo the value in the form of `key=value`. Enable the `capture-output` for the shell action.
4. This is your MR action. Now access the action data using the Oozie EL functions. e.g. `${wf:actionData('ShellAction')['key']}`, pass this value to the `mapred.reduce.tasks` in the `configuration` tag of the MR action.

Comment: is it possible to pass the 'key' as an argument too?