# Create var in hive query running in Ozzie

Tags: hadoop, hive, oozie

How to create variable in hive query running in Oozie(Hue) and pass this variable in next step of Oozie job to example Email job or Shell?

I try this :

```
set q1=select sum(br) from auth;
```

Accessing q1 in Email job like this :${hiveconf:q1}
throw error :

```
EL_ERROR    Encountered ": q1 }", expected one of ["}", ".", ">", "gt", "<", "lt", "==", "eq", "<=", "le", ">=", "ge", "!=", "ne", "[", "+", "-", "*", "/", "div", "%", "mod", "and", "&&", "or", "||", ":", <IDENTIFIER>, "(", "?"]
```

Maybe I do it wrong and there is completely different solution? Or maybe itss hue error?

Comment: The way you have done will never work. I can tell you an work around. You can use this approach: [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38371151/2254048)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically calculating oozie parameter (number of reducers for MR action)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38325306/dynamically-calculating-oozie-parameter-number-of-reducers-for-mr-action). `I have marked duplicate, approach wise.`